# How can I have a abstract class pointer as a Q_PROPERTY?

Tags: c++, qml, qtquick2

I am trying to use instances of an abstract class as a property in one of my extended QQuickItems. I have a basic class, like this:

```
class VizFactory : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT;
    Q_PROPERTY(VisualizationOptions * options READ options WRITE setOptions);

   private:
    VisualizationOptions * m_visualizationOptions;

   public:
    VizFactory(QQuickItem * parent = 0) : QQuickItem(parent) {}
    ~VizFactory() {}

    VisualizationOptions * options() const;
    void setOptions(VisualizationOptions * options);
};
```

Where `VisualizationOptions` is an abstract class that extends some other classes, like `LayoutOptions` and `FooOptions`:

```
class VisualizationOptions : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

   public:
    VisualizationOptions(QObject * parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}
    virtual std::string getVisualizationName() const = 0;
};
```

I register everything in my main file using:

```
qmlRegisterUncreatableType<VisualizationOptions>("Wormhole", 1, 0, "VisualizationOptions",
                                                 QString("Cannot create abstract class VisualizationOptions"));
qmlRegisterType<LayoutOptions>("Wormhole", 1, 0, "LayoutOptions");
qmlRegisterType<FooOptions>("Wormhole", 1, 0, "FooOptions");
```

Then, I try to use it in a qml file by putting in:

```
VizFactory {
    options: LayoutOptions {
        type: "row"

        FooOptions {}
        LayoutOptions {
            type: "col"
            FooOptions {}
            FooOptions {}
        }
    }
}
```

But, the error I'm getting is from the qml file on the line defining `options`, saying: "Cannot assign to non-existent default property". Why is this happening? Am I not registering the types correctly? Am I instantiating the objects in QML incorrectly?

Comment: Does it work when the class is not abstract?

Comment: No. I just tried registering it as a QML Type (`qmlRegisterType`), and it gave the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not caused by the abstract class but because the `QObject`s do not have [`childItems`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickitem.html#childItems), unlike the `QQuickItem` that does have that property.

The same thing you could see if you use QtObject:

```
QtObject{
    QtObject{

    }
}
```

message:

> Cannot assign to non-existent default property

So there are 3 possible solutions:

- Make VisualizationOptions inherit from QQuickItem and so you can have children.
- Do not assign children, for example with your code should work the following:

  ```
  VizFactory{
      options: LayoutOptions{
      }
  }
  ```
- use [QQmlListproperty](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmllistproperty.html)

I will show an example using the third method:

```
class VisualizationOptions: public QObject{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QQmlListProperty<VisualizationOptions> childOptions READ options)
public:
    using QObject::QObject;
    virtual std::string getVisualizationName() const = 0;
    QQmlListProperty<VisualizationOptions> options(){
        return QQmlListProperty<VisualizationOptions>(this, this,
                                                      &VisualizationOptions::appendOption,
                                                      &VisualizationOptions::optionCount,
                                                      &VisualizationOptions::option,
                                                      &VisualizationOptions::clearOptions);
    }
    void appendOption(VisualizationOptions* p) {
        m_childsoptions.append(p);
    }
    int optionCount() const{
        return m_childsoptions.count();
    }
    VisualizationOptions *option(int index) const{
        return m_childsoptions.at(index);
    }
    void clearOptions() {
        m_childsoptions.clear();
    }
private:
    static void appendOption(QQmlListProperty<VisualizationOptions>* list, VisualizationOptions* p) {
        reinterpret_cast<VisualizationOptions* >(list->data)->appendOption(p);
    }
    static void clearOptions(QQmlListProperty<VisualizationOptions>* list) {
        reinterpret_cast<VisualizationOptions* >(list->data)->clearOptions();
    }
    static VisualizationOptions* option(QQmlListProperty<VisualizationOptions>* list, int i) {
        return reinterpret_cast< VisualizationOptions* >(list->data)->option(i);
    }
    static int optionCount(QQmlListProperty<VisualizationOptions>* list) {
        return reinterpret_cast< VisualizationOptions* >(list->data)->optionCount();
    }
    QVector<VisualizationOptions *> m_childsoptions;
};
```

***.qml**

```
VizFactory{
    options:
        LayoutOptions{
        type: "row"
        childOptions: [
            FooOptions{},
            LayoutOptions{
                type: "col"
                childOptions: [
                    FooOptions {},
                    FooOptions {}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

<sub>You can find the complete code in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/51757280).</sub>

Comment: 3rd solution: add a default `QQmlListproperty` property

Comment: @GrecKo Of course, there is also this possibility, I will add it

Comment: @eyllanesc, wow. I learned so much from that post. Keep up the good work!